# SVN merge files

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, merge

I'm using TortoiseSVN as my SVN client.

How can I know if a file was merged in the past ?

Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to see that a currently synchronised file has previously been merged?

Comment: yes. in the revision graph, or maybe in the log window of the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the file, and go to TortoiseSVN>Show log - that should show you all actions performed on the file in the past. Tick the 'Include merged revisions' tickbox at the bottom of the dialog and you should be able to track your merges.

[See this link for more details](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html#id689616).

Comment: do you mean a green line in the log window ?

Comment: At the bottom of the Log Messages dialog there's a tickbox that reads 'Include merged revisions' - tick that and you should be able to see your merges. I've edited my answer to include a good link.

Comment: It works. thanks.
1. Is there a way to see it in the revision graph to TortoiseSVN like the graph in WinCVS ?
2. if I converted the repository from CVS, do the merges made before will be shown as well ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with WinCVS, but try right clicking the file and selecting TortoiseSVN>Revision graph?